# App-crash on HoloLens(1st. gen)-Emulator when enabling 'Spatial Awareness System' in MRTK 2.3

Tags: windows, unity-game-engine, hololens, windows-mixed-reality, hololens-emulator

i recently set up required software for development for the Microsoft HoloLens(1st. gen) with the newest version of the HoloLens(1st. gen) emulator (followed the MRTK-Guide: https://microsoft.github.io/MixedRealityToolkit-Unity/Documentation/GettingStartedWithTheMRTK.html#get-the-latest-mrtk-unity-packages). I already tested some example scenes from the MRTK on the emulator and everything works as expected. However, when i test the SpatialAwarenessMeshDemo, the app starts within the emulator with the unity start-screen. Then the scene is visible but after 1-2s the scene disappears and exceptions are thrown.
Visual Studio Log:

```
'HoloLensTest.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\ntdll.dll'. 
'HoloLensTest.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\KernelBase.dll'. 
'HoloLensTest.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\combase.dll'. 
'HoloLensTest.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\ucrtbase.dll'. 
'HoloLensTest.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\rpcrt4.dll'. 
'HoloLensTest.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\kernel32legacy.dll'. 
'HoloLensTest.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\bcryptprimitives.dll'. 
'HoloLensTest.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'U:\Programs\WindowsApps\Microsoft.VCLibs.140.00.Debug_14.0.27323.0_x86__8wekyb3d8bbwe\vccorlib140d_app.dll'. 
'HoloLensTest.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\oleaut32.dll'. 
'HoloLensTest.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\msvcp_win.dll'. 
'HoloLensTest.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'U:\Programs\WindowsApps\Microsoft.VCLibs.140.00.Debug_14.0.27323.0_x86__8wekyb3d8bbwe\vcruntime140d_app.dll'. 
'HoloLensTest.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'U:\Users\DefaultAccount\AppData\Local\DevelopmentFiles\Template3DVS.Debug_Win32.Christopher\ucrtbased.dll'. 
'HoloLensTest.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'U:\Programs\WindowsApps\Microsoft.VCLibs.140.00.Debug_14.0.27323.0_x86__8wekyb3d8bbwe\msvcp140d_app.dll'. 
'HoloLensTest.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\Forwarders\kernel32.dll'. 
The thread 0x1578 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
'HoloLensTest.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\procthreadexthost.dll'. 
'HoloLensTest.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\msvcrt.dll'. 
'HoloLensTest.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\kernel.appcore.dll'. 
'HoloLensTest.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\twinapi.appcore.dll'. 
'HoloLensTest.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\sechost.dll'. 
'HoloLensTest.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\rmclient.dll'. 
'HoloLensTest.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\WinTypes.dll'. 
'HoloLensTest.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\SHCore.dll'. 
'HoloLensTest.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\Windows.UI.dll'. 
'HoloLensTest.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\win32u.dll'. 
'HoloLensTest.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\dcomp.dll'. 
'HoloLensTest.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\MinUser.dll'. 
'HoloLensTest.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\TextInputFramework.dll'. 
'HoloLensTest.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\InputHost.dll'. 
'HoloLensTest.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\dxgi.dll'. 
'HoloLensTest.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\gdi32.dll'. 
'HoloLensTest.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\CoreUIComponents.dll'. 
'HoloLensTest.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\gdi32min.dll'. 
'HoloLensTest.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\CoreMessaging.dll'. 
'HoloLensTest.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\d2d1.dll'. 
'HoloLensTest.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\d3d11.dll'. 
'HoloLensTest.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\ntmarta.dll'. 
'HoloLensTest.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\advapi32legacy.dll'. 
'HoloLensTest.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\sspicli.dll'. 
'HoloLensTest.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\propsys.dll'. 
'HoloLensTest.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\bcrypt.dll'. 
'HoloLensTest.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\OneCoreUAPCommonProxyStub.dll'. 
'HoloLensTest.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\Windows.Graphics.dll'. 
'HoloLensTest.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\cfgmgr32.dll'. 
'HoloLensTest.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\Windows.Shell.ServiceHostBuilder.dll'. 
'HoloLensTest.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'U:\Users\DefaultAccount\AppData\Local\DevelopmentFiles\Template3DVS.Debug_Win32.Christopher\UnityPlayer.dll'. 
'HoloLensTest.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\ws2_32.dll'. 
'HoloLensTest.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\D3D12.dll'. 
'HoloLensTest.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\mfplat.dll'. 
'HoloLensTest.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\mfreadwrite.dll'. 
'HoloLensTest.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'U:\Programs\WindowsApps\Microsoft.VCLibs.140.00.Debug_14.0.27323.0_x86__8wekyb3d8bbwe\vccorlib140_app.dll'. 
'HoloLensTest.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\Forwarders\version.dll'. 
'HoloLensTest.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\crypt32.dll'. 
'HoloLensTest.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\MMDevAPI.dll'. 
'HoloLensTest.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'U:\Programs\WindowsApps\Microsoft.VCLibs.140.00.Debug_14.0.27323.0_x86__8wekyb3d8bbwe\vcruntime140_app.dll'. 
'HoloLensTest.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\msasn1.dll'. 
'HoloLensTest.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'U:\Programs\WindowsApps\Microsoft.VCLibs.140.00.Debug_14.0.27323.0_x86__8wekyb3d8bbwe\msvcp140_app.dll'. 
'HoloLensTest.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\RTWorkQ.dll'. 
'HoloLensTest.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\devobj.dll'. 
'HoloLensTest.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\ExecModelClient.dll'. 
'HoloLensTest.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.dll'. 
'HoloLensTest.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\windows.storage.dll'. 
'HoloLensTest.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\profapi.dll'. 
'HoloLensTest.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\powrprof.dll'. 
'HoloLensTest.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\shlwapi_onecore.dll'. 
'HoloLensTest.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\MrmCoreR.dll'. 
CreateDirectory 'C:/Data' failed: Operation has failed with error 0xb7: Cannot create a file when that file already exists.
 (current dir: C:/Data/Users/DefaultAccount/AppData/Local/DevelopmentFiles/Template3DVS.Debug_Win32.Christopher/Data)
Logging to C:/Data/Users/Visitor0/AppData/Local/Packages/Template3D_pzq3xp76mxafg/TempState/UnityPlayer.log
[0.322811 / 0.399454] - Initializing Unity runtime
Loading native plugins
  Loading AudioPluginMsHRTF.dll
'HoloLensTest.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'U:\Users\DefaultAccount\AppData\Local\DevelopmentFiles\Template3DVS.Debug_Win32.Christopher\AudioPluginMsHRTF.dll'. 
'HoloLensTest.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\HrtfApo.dll'. 
Module information:
 Built with Compiler Ver '191627012'
 Built from '2019.2/staging' branch
 Version is '2019.2.21f1 (9d528d026557)'
 Debug build
 Application type 'D3D'
'HoloLensTest.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\Windows.Devices.Enumeration.dll'. 
'HoloLensTest.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\deviceassociation.dll'. 
'HoloLensTest.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\execmodelproxy.dll'. 
Exception thrown at 0x7770F2B2 in HoloLensTest.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: Cn::XH at memory location 0x013CE754.
onecoreuap\windows\moderncore\inputv2\inputhost\components\cursor\client\cursorclient.cpp(43)\InputHost.dll!6E59AB33: (caller: 6E59ACAC) ReturnHr(1) tid(1678) 87B20809 onecoreuap\windows\moderncore\inputv2\inputhost\components\cursor\client\cursorclient.cpp(75)\InputHost.dll!6E59ACC3: (caller: 6E56959D) ReturnHr(2) tid(1678) 87B20809 'HoloLensTest.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\UiaManager.dll'. 
'HoloLensTest.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\Windows.UI.Core.TextInput.dll'. 
[0.000716 / 0.617966] - AppCallbacks::SetCoreWindowEvents
'HoloLensTest.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\Windows.Perception.Stub.dll'. 
'HoloLensTest.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\Windows.Mirage.dll'. 
wil(439)\Windows.Mirage.dll!6EA6C73F: (caller: 6EA6C564) ReturnHr(1) tid(d64) 80070005 Access is denied.
'HoloLensTest.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\d3d10warp.dll'. 
'HoloLensTest.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\ResourcePolicyClient.dll'. 
'HoloLensTest.exe' (Win32): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\System32\ResourcePolicyClient.dll'
[0.080414 / 0.698570] - AppCallbacks::InitializeD3DWindow
'HoloLensTest.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\cryptbase.dll'. 
[0.740232 / 0.740232] - OnActivated event.
[0.003292 / 0.743524] - OnCoreWindowSizeChanged event (0.00, 0.00, 853.33, 480.00), m_Initialized=False.
[0.033297 / 0.776821] - OnVisibilityChanged event - Visible.
[0.004851 / 0.781672] - OnWindowActivated event - CodeActivated.
 OS 'Windows 10 (10.0.17763)'
'HoloLensTest.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'U:\Users\DefaultAccount\AppData\Local\DevelopmentFiles\Template3DVS.Debug_Win32.Christopher\GameAssembly.dll'. Symbols loaded.
[2.106498 / 2.888170] - OnCoreWindowSizeChanged event (0.00, 0.00, 853.33, 480.00), m_Initialized=False.
'HoloLensTest.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\IPHLPAPI.DLL'. 
PlayerConnection initialized from C:/Data/Users/DefaultAccount/AppData/Local/DevelopmentFiles/Template3DVS.Debug_Win32.Christopher/Data (debug = 0)
'HoloLensTest.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\mswsock.dll'. 
'HoloLensTest.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\Windows.Networking.Connectivity.dll'. 
'HoloLensTest.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\Windows.Networking.HostName.dll'. 
'HoloLensTest.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\wshbth.dll'. 
'HoloLensTest.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\dnsapi.dll'. 
'HoloLensTest.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\nsi.dll'. 
'HoloLensTest.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\dhcpcsvc6.dll'. 
'HoloLensTest.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\dhcpcsvc.dll'. 
Invalid parameter passed to C runtime function.
Invalid parameter passed to C runtime function.
'HoloLensTest.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\FWPUCLNT.DLL'. 
PlayerConnection initialized network socket : 0.0.0.0 55287
'HoloLensTest.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\nlaapi.dll'. 
'HoloLensTest.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\Windows.ApplicationModel.dll'. 
Multi-casting "[IP] 172.17.191.38 [Port] 55287 [Flags] 2 [Guid] 1043895467 [EditorId] 0 [Version] 1048832 [Id] UWPPlayerX86(minwinpc) [Debug] 0 [PackageName] Template3D_pzq3xp76mxafg" to [225.0.0.222:54997]...
Started listening to [0.0.0.0:55287]
PlayerConnection already initialized - listening to [0.0.0.0:55287]
[3.073006 / 3.514748] - Initialize
[XR] Discovering subsystems at path C:/Data/Users/DefaultAccount/AppData/Local/DevelopmentFiles/Template3DVS.Debug_Win32.Christopher/Data/UnitySubsystems
GfxDevice: creating device client; threaded=1
'HoloLensTest.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\DXGIDebug.dll'. 
'HoloLensTest.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\d3d11_3SDKLayers.dll'. 
Successfully created d3d11 device with debug flag.
Direct3D:
    Version:  Direct3D 11.0 [level 11.1]
    Renderer: Microsoft Basic Render Driver (ID=0x8c)
    Vendor:   (null)
    VRAM:     1023 MB
Initialize engine version: 2019.2.21f1 (9d528d026557)
[AudioManager] InitNormal(tryDeviceDefaults = false, preferredOutputType = FMOD_OUTPUTTYPE_AUTODETECT) attempt with hardAudioDisable: false
[AudioManager] Setting output to FMOD_OUTPUTTYPE_AUTODETECT
'HoloLensTest.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\Windows.Media.Devices.dll'. 
'HoloLensTest.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\DevDispItemProvider.dll'. 
'HoloLensTest.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\AudioSes.dll'. 
'HoloLensTest.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\avrt.dll'. 
'HoloLensTest.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\ResourcePolicyClient.dll'. 
'HoloLensTest.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\threadpoolwinrt.dll'. 
[AudioManager] InitNormal succeeded with output "FMOD_OUTPUTTYPE_WASAPI". Driver name is "Speakers (Null Audio Driver)". Speaker mode is "FMOD_SPEAKERMODE_STEREO"
The thread 0x12e0 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x12bc has exited with code 0 (0x0).
'HoloLensTest.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\Windows.Gaming.Input.dll'. 
onecoreuap\xbox\devices\api\winrt\pnpapiwrapper.cpp(385)\Windows.Gaming.Input.dll!6FFAF86B: (caller: 6FFB2723) ReturnHr(1) tid(b90) 8685C003 onecoreuap\xbox\devices\api\winrt\pnpapiwrapper.cpp(385)\Windows.Gaming.Input.dll!6FFAF86B: (caller: 6FFB2723) ReturnHr(2) tid(b90) 8685C003 onecoreuap\xbox\devices\api\winrt\pnpapiwrapper.cpp(385)\Windows.Gaming.Input.dll!6FFAF86B: (caller: 6FFB2723) ReturnHr(3) tid(b90) 8685C003 onecoreuap\xbox\devices\api\winrt\pnpapiwrapper.cpp(385)\Windows.Gaming.Input.dll!6FFAF86B: (caller: 6FFB2723) ReturnHr(4) tid(b90) 8685C003 onecoreuap\xbox\devices\api\winrt\pnpapiwrapper.cpp(385)\Windows.Gaming.Input.dll!6FFAF86B: (caller: 6FFB2723) ReturnHr(5) tid(b90) 8685C003 onecoreuap\xbox\devices\api\winrt\pnpapiwrapper.cpp(385)\Windows.Gaming.Input.dll!6FFAF86B: (caller: 6FFB2723) ReturnHr(6) tid(b90) 8685C003 onecoreuap\xbox\devices\api\winrt\pnpapiwrapper.cpp(385)\Windows.Gaming.Input.dll!6FFAF86B: (caller: 6FFB2723) ReturnHr(7) tid(b90) 8685C003 [0.001229 / 5.339379] - AppCallbacks::SetupInputEvents
'HoloLensTest.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\Windows.Devices.Sensors.dll'. 
'HoloLensTest.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\biwinrt.dll'. 
Exception thrown at 0x7770F2B2 (KernelBase.dll) in HoloLensTest.exe: WinRT originate error - 0x80040111 : 'Windows.UI.WindowManagement.DisplayRegion'.
'HoloLensTest.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\userenv.dll'. 
'HoloLensTest.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\profext.dll'. 
onecoreuap\drivers\mobilepc\sensors\convergence\api\winrt\public\internal\viewpositiontrackerinternal.h(94)\Windows.Devices.Sensors.dll!506F33ED: (caller: 506F240F) Exception(1) tid(1678) 80040111 ClassFactory cannot supply requested class
Exception thrown at 0x7770F2B2 in HoloLensTest.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: wil::ResultException at memory location 0x013CDB40.
Exception thrown at 0x7770F2B2 in HoloLensTest.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: [rethrow] at memory location 0x00000000.
onecoreuap\drivers\mobilepc\sensors\convergence\api\winrt\public\internal\simpleorientation.cpp(127)\Windows.Devices.Sensors.dll!506F1AC7: (caller: 506EB61C) Exception(2) tid(1678) 80070490 Element not found.
Exception thrown at 0x7770F2B2 in HoloLensTest.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: wil::ResultException at memory location 0x013CDD88.
Exception thrown at 0x7770F2B2 in HoloLensTest.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: [rethrow] at memory location 0x00000000.
onecoreuap\drivers\mobilepc\sensors\convergence\api\winrt\public\internal\sensorserver.cpp(46)\Windows.Devices.Sensors.dll!506E8581: (caller: 506E593F) ReturnHr(1) tid(1678) 80070490 Element not found.
onecoreuap\drivers\mobilepc\sensors\convergence\api\winrt\public\lib\simpleorientationsensor.cpp(160)\Windows.Devices.Sensors.dll!5074B90D: (caller: 50749E09) ReturnHr(2) tid(1678) 80070490 Element not found.
[0.061399 / 5.401353] - AppCallbacks::SetupOrientationSensorEvents
'HoloLensTest.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\windows.applicationmodel.datatransfer.dll'. 
'HoloLensTest.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\coml2.dll'. 
'HoloLensTest.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\iertutil.dll'. 
'HoloLensTest.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\ie_shims.dll'. 
'HoloLensTest.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\ClipboardServer.dll'. 
[0.152667 / 5.458863] - AppCallbacks::Load
[2.571148 / 5.459318] - Starting first scene loading
The following GlobalManagers were stripped from the build (Either because they're not used or not supported on this platform):
  ClusterInputManager
If your machine has multiple graphics adapters, Unity may have created a WindowContext on the wrong adapter. If you experience a black screen when playing, please restart the Editor.

(Filename: C:\buildslave\unity\build\Modules/VR/VRDevice.cpp Line: 323)

onecoreuap\analog\input\holographicdriverclientlib\lib\holographicdriverhandlewrapper.h(542)\Windows.Mirage.dll!6EA719A2: (caller: 6EA7177F) ReturnHr(2) tid(1674) 8007007B The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.
    CallContext:[\OpenHolographicDevice] 
onecoreuap\analog\input\holographicdriverclientlib\lib\holographicdriverhandlewrapper.h(428)\Windows.Mirage.dll!6EA717C5: (caller: 6EA75CDB) Exception(1) tid(1674) 8007007B The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.
    CallContext:[\OpenHolographicDevice] 
Exception thrown at 0x7770F2B2 in HoloLensTest.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: wil::ResultException at memory location 0x01FCCBF8.
Exception thrown at 0x7770F2B2 in HoloLensTest.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: [rethrow] at memory location 0x00000000.
onecoreuap\analog\input\holographicdriverclientlib\lib\spatialgraphdriverclient.cpp(2174)\Windows.Mirage.dll!6EA7370F: (caller: 6EA73573) ReturnHr(3) tid(1674) 8007007B The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.
onecoreuap\analog\input\holographicdriverclientlib\lib\holographicdriverhandlewrapper.h(542)\Windows.Mirage.dll!6EA719A2: (caller: 6EA7177F) ReturnHr(4) tid(158c) 8007007B The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.
    CallContext:[\OpenHolographicDevice] 
onecoreuap\analog\input\holographicdriverclientlib\lib\holographicdriverhandlewrapper.h(428)\Windows.Mirage.dll!6EA717C5: (caller: 6EA75CDB) Exception(2) tid(158c) 8007007B The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.
    CallContext:[\OpenHolographicDevice] 
Exception thrown at 0x7770F2B2 in HoloLensTest.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: wil::ResultException at memory location 0x08B3DE98.
Exception thrown at 0x7770F2B2 in HoloLensTest.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: [rethrow] at memory location 0x00000000.
onecoreuap\analog\input\holographicdriverclientlib\lib\spatialgraphdriverclient.cpp(2174)\Windows.Mirage.dll!6EA7370F: (caller: 6EA73573) ReturnHr(5) tid(158c) 8007007B The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.
[0.023743 / 5.483061] - OnCoreWindowSizeChanged event (0.00, 0.00, 845.33, 480.00), m_Initialized=True.
Created eye textures with a "texture array" layout.  The "single-pass instancing" stereo mode will be used.

[0.080543 / 5.563604] - Finishing first scene loading
[0.000505 / 5.564109] - First level loaded
[0.000411 / 5.564521] - PerformUpdateAndRender started
Windows Mixed Reality spatial locatability state changed to Active.

(Filename: C:\buildslave\unity\build\Modules/VR/HoloLens/HoloLensWorldManager.cpp Line: 324)

End showing splash screen.
UnloadTime: 2.198500 ms
'HoloLensTest.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\OneCoreCommonProxyStub.dll'. 
'HoloLensTest.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\Windows.System.Profile.SystemId.dll'. 
'HoloLensTest.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\Clipc.dll'. 
'HoloLensTest.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\cryptsp.dll'. 
'HoloLensTest.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\CryptoWinRT.dll'. 
Failed to calculate boundary bounds.
UnityEngine.DebugLogHandler:Internal_Log(LogType, LogOption, String, Object)
UnityEngine.DebugLogHandler:LogFormat(LogType, Object, String, Object[])
UnityEngine.Logger:Log(LogType, Object)
UnityEngine.Debug:LogWarning(Object)
Microsoft.MixedReality.Toolkit.Boundary.BaseBoundarySystem:CalculateBoundaryBounds()
Microsoft.MixedReality.Toolkit.Boundary.BaseBoundarySystem:Initialize()
Microsoft.MixedReality.Toolkit.Boundary.MixedRealityBoundarySystem:Initialize()
Microsoft.MixedReality.Toolkit.<>c:<InitializeAllServices>b__60_0(IMixedRealityService)
System.Action`1:Invoke(T)
Microsoft.MixedReality.Toolkit.MixedRealityToolkit:ExecuteOnAllServicesInOrder(Action`1)
Microsoft.MixedReality.Toolkit.MixedRealityToolkit:InitializeAllServices()
Microsoft.MixedReality.Toolkit.MixedRealityToolkit:InitializeServiceLocator()
Microsoft.MixedReality.Toolkit.MixedRealityToolkit:InitializeInstance()
Microsoft.MixedReality.Toolkit.MixedRealityToolkit:RegisterInstance(MixedRealityToolkit, Boolean)
Microsoft.MixedReality.Toolkit.MixedRealityToolkit:Awake()

(Filename: C:\buildslave\unity\build\Runtime/Export/Debug/Debug.bindings.h Line: 35)

'HoloLensTest.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\rometadata.dll'. 
'HoloLensTest.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\WinMetadata\Windows.Graphics.winmd'. Module was built without symbols.
The thread 0x310 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
'HoloLensTest.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\Windows.Media.Speech.dll'. 
'HoloLensTest.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\msvcp110_win.dll'. 
'HoloLensTest.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\BCP47Langs.dll'. 
'HoloLensTest.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\urlmon.dll'. 
'HoloLensTest.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\Speech_OneCore\Common\sapi_onecore.dll'. 
'HoloLensTest.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\winmmbase.dll'. 
'HoloLensTest.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\winhttp.dll'. 
'HoloLensTest.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\rsaenh.dll'. 
'HoloLensTest.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\msxml6.dll'. 
'HoloLensTest.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\ole32_wp.dll'. 
'HoloLensTest.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\Windows.Globalization.dll'. 
'HoloLensTest.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\BCP47mrm.dll'. 
'HoloLensTest.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\FlightSettings.dll'. 
'HoloLensTest.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\bcd.dll'. 
'HoloLensTest.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\Speech_OneCore\Common\SpeechServiceWinRTApi.ProxyStub.dll'. 
onecoreuap\enduser\nui\onecore\sapi\sapi\sr\srcloudpolicy.cpp(255)\sapi_onecore.dll!5E2B61EA: (caller: 5E2B6621) ReturnHr(1) tid(b98) 80070005 Access is denied.
'HoloLensTest.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\Speech_OneCore\Engines\SR\spsrx_onecore.dll'. 
'HoloLensTest.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\wininet.dll'. 
Exception thrown at 0x7770F2B2 (KernelBase.dll) in HoloLensTest.exe: 0x40080202: WinRT transform error (parameters: 0x8000000B, 0x80070490, 0x00000014, 0x0F5FE224).
'HoloLensTest.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\tokenbinding.dll'. 
'HoloLensTest.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\OnDemandConnRouteHelper.dll'. 
'HoloLensTest.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\winnsi.dll'. 
'HoloLensTest.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\rasapi32.dll'. 
'HoloLensTest.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\rasman.dll'. 
[5.896206 / 11.460727] - OnWindowActivated event - Deactivated.
The thread 0x173c has exited with code 0 (0x0).
'HoloLensTest.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\cryptnet.dll'. 
'HoloLensTest.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\webio.dll'. 
The thread 0x614 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
'HoloLensTest.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\cabinet.dll'. 
Invalid parameter passed to C runtime function.
Invalid parameter passed to C runtime function.
The thread 0x9d0 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
Exception thrown at 0x7770F2B2 (KernelBase.dll) in HoloLensTest.exe: WinRT originate error - 0x80040111 : 'Windows.UI.WindowManagement.DisplayRegion'.
onecoreuap\drivers\mobilepc\sensors\convergence\api\winrt\public\internal\viewpositiontrackerinternal.h(94)\Windows.Devices.Sensors.dll!506F33ED: (caller: 506F240F) Exception(3) tid(1674) 80040111 ClassFactory cannot supply requested class
Exception thrown at 0x7770F2B2 in HoloLensTest.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: wil::ResultException at memory location 0x01FCC900.
Exception thrown at 0x7770F2B2 in HoloLensTest.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: [rethrow] at memory location 0x00000000.
onecoreuap\drivers\mobilepc\sensors\convergence\api\winrt\public\internal\sensor.cpp(179)\Windows.Devices.Sensors.dll!506EF4AC: (caller: 506EB61C) Exception(4) tid(1674) 80070490 Element not found.
Exception thrown at 0x7770F2B2 in HoloLensTest.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: wil::ResultException at memory location 0x01FCCB48.
Exception thrown at 0x7770F2B2 in HoloLensTest.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: [rethrow] at memory location 0x00000000.
onecoreuap\drivers\mobilepc\sensors\convergence\api\winrt\public\internal\sensorserver.cpp(46)\Windows.Devices.Sensors.dll!506E8581: (caller: 506E593F) ReturnHr(3) tid(1674) 80070490 Element not found.
Exception thrown at 0x7770F2B2 (KernelBase.dll) in HoloLensTest.exe: WinRT originate error - 0x80040111 : 'Windows.UI.WindowManagement.DisplayRegion'.
onecoreuap\drivers\mobilepc\sensors\convergence\api\winrt\public\internal\viewpositiontrackerinternal.h(94)\Windows.Devices.Sensors.dll!506F33ED: (caller: 506F240F) Exception(5) tid(1674) 80040111 ClassFactory cannot supply requested class
Exception thrown at 0x7770F2B2 in HoloLensTest.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: wil::ResultException at memory location 0x01FCC8D0.
Exception thrown at 0x7770F2B2 in HoloLensTest.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: [rethrow] at memory location 0x00000000.
onecoreuap\drivers\mobilepc\sensors\convergence\api\winrt\public\internal\sensor.cpp(179)\Windows.Devices.Sensors.dll!506EF4AC: (caller: 506EB61C) Exception(6) tid(1674) 80070490 Element not found.
Exception thrown at 0x7770F2B2 in HoloLensTest.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: wil::ResultException at memory location 0x01FCCB18.
Exception thrown at 0x7770F2B2 in HoloLensTest.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: [rethrow] at memory location 0x00000000.
onecoreuap\drivers\mobilepc\sensors\convergence\api\winrt\public\internal\sensorserver.cpp(46)\Windows.Devices.Sensors.dll!506E8581: (caller: 506E593F) ReturnHr(4) tid(1674) 80070490 Element not found.
Exception thrown at 0x7770F2B2 (KernelBase.dll) in HoloLensTest.exe: WinRT originate error - 0x80040111 : 'Windows.UI.WindowManagement.DisplayRegion'.
onecoreuap\drivers\mobilepc\sensors\convergence\api\winrt\public\internal\viewpositiontrackerinternal.h(94)\Windows.Devices.Sensors.dll!506F33ED: (caller: 506F240F) Exception(7) tid(1674) 80040111 ClassFactory cannot supply requested class
Exception thrown at 0x7770F2B2 in HoloLensTest.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: wil::ResultException at memory location 0x01FCC860.
Exception thrown at 0x7770F2B2 in HoloLensTest.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: [rethrow] at memory location 0x00000000.
onecoreuap\drivers\mobilepc\sensors\convergence\api\winrt\public\internal\sensor.cpp(179)\Windows.Devices.Sensors.dll!506EF4AC: (caller: 506EB61C) Exception(8) tid(1674) 80070490 Element not found.
Exception thrown at 0x7770F2B2 in HoloLensTest.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: wil::ResultException at memory location 0x01FCCAA8.
Exception thrown at 0x7770F2B2 in HoloLensTest.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: [rethrow] at memory location 0x00000000.
onecoreuap\drivers\mobilepc\sensors\convergence\api\winrt\public\internal\sensorserver.cpp(46)\Windows.Devices.Sensors.dll!506E8581: (caller: 506E593F) ReturnHr(5) tid(1674) 80070490 Element not found.
Exception thrown at 0x7770F2B2 (KernelBase.dll) in HoloLensTest.exe: WinRT originate error - 0x80040111 : 'Windows.UI.WindowManagement.DisplayRegion'.
onecoreuap\drivers\mobilepc\sensors\convergence\api\winrt\public\internal\viewpositiontrackerinternal.h(94)\Windows.Devices.Sensors.dll!506F33ED: (caller: 506F240F) Exception(9) tid(1674) 80040111 ClassFactory cannot supply requested class
Exception thrown at 0x7770F2B2 in HoloLensTest.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: wil::ResultException at memory location 0x01FCC940.
Exception thrown at 0x7770F2B2 in HoloLensTest.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: [rethrow] at memory location 0x00000000.
onecoreuap\drivers\mobilepc\sensors\convergence\api\winrt\public\internal\sensor.cpp(179)\Windows.Devices.Sensors.dll!506EF4AC: (caller: 506EB61C) Exception(10) tid(1674) 80070490 Element not found.
Exception thrown at 0x7770F2B2 in HoloLensTest.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: wil::ResultException at memory location 0x01FCCB88.
Exception thrown at 0x7770F2B2 in HoloLensTest.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: [rethrow] at memory location 0x00000000.
onecoreuap\drivers\mobilepc\sensors\convergence\api\winrt\public\internal\sensorserver.cpp(46)\Windows.Devices.Sensors.dll!506E8581: (caller: 506E593F) ReturnHr(6) tid(1674) 80070490 Element not found.
Exception thrown at 0x7770F2B2 in HoloLensTest.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: Il2CppExceptionWrapper at memory location 0x01FCDDBC.
The thread 0x778 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
Failed to retrieve bytes for vertex positions from surface mesh!

(Filename: C:\buildslave\unity\build\Modules/VR/HoloLens/SpatialMapping/SpatialSurface.cpp Line: 127)

HoloLensTest.exe has triggered a breakpoint.
```

After trying out with different scenes this only happens if i choose a profile in the MixedRealityToolki-object where 'Enable Spatial Awareness System' is enabled.
I already tried cloning and modifing the DefaultHoloLens1ConfigurationProfile by enabling 'Enable Spatial Awareness System' and adding the 'SpatialObjectMeshObserver' to the Spatial Observer list.
I double-checked my project-settings and the Unity-Package-Manager for the right settings.

Does someone has a clue about what the cause of this problem might be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So i ironically found a solution for this just after posting the question:
I stumbled about  this https://github.com/Microsoft/MixedRealityToolkit-Unity/issues/3554 so i installed an older version of the HoloLens(1st. gen) emulator and everything works fine.
Older versions: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/hololens-emulator-archive

version that worked for me: `HoloLens Emulator build 10.0.17134.80`